# SQL Server self recursive horizontal join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a query which provides hierarchical data in a horizontal way. The levels of depth are variable, it is ok if there are many empty fields. The only rows that should exist should be just children. Here's an example of what I need:

```
ID   |Value  |ID_Parent
-----|-------|---------
1    |NULL   |NULL
2    |NULL   |1
3    |30     |1
4    |NULL   |2
5    |20     |4
6    |10     |NULL
```

So the output to this would be something like:

```
ID   |Value  |Ancestor_1 |Ancestor_2 |Ancestor_3
-----|-------|-----------|-----------|----------
3    |30     |1          |NULL       |NULL
5    |20     |1          |2          |4
6    |10     |NULL       |NULL       |NULL
```

It is needed that the ancestors are labeled 1-to-n as farest-to-nearest.
A tree view of the data would be this one:

```
1->/2->4->5
   \3
6
```

I've found a solution for fixed levels but I was wondering if this can be done in SQL Server.

Comment: Sure it can be done. You need to add a level to your recursive cte query so you know where it is in the hierarchy. Then you can use a dynamic crosstab or dynamic pivot to turn rows into columns.

Comment: Using hierarchyid type may help (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)

Comment: @Mecek not sure that is relevant here. The OP is using an adjacency list and they want to pivot the list of ancestors. Switching a hierarchyID isn't going to fix that.

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange, I'll try that!